# Can we overwrite "enabled" in @BeforeTest in TestNg via Vm argument?

Tags: java, testng

Whether we can disable `@BeforeTest` via vm argument which has default `enabled=true`?

```
@BeforeTest(enabled = true)
public void someMethod(){
...}
```

I do not want to run `someMethod`. I do not want to add any parameter and check the condition also.

Comment: Please, explain it more and enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well do this using `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` implementation.

Below is a sample that shows how the transformer looks like [ Make sure you are using the latest released version of TestNG viz., `7.1.0` as of today ]

Points to remember:

- Make sure you wire in the annotation transformer only via the suite file.
- To selectively disable any configuration method (not just `@BeforeTest`), you just pass in the fully qualified method name as comma separated values as a JVM argument [ for e.g., `-Dmethods.disable=com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn59840389.SampleTestClass#skippingBeforeTest` ]. The class name and method name has to be seperated using `#` and multiple values can be separated using `,`

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.IConfigurationAnnotation;

public class SampleAnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  @Override
  public void transform(
      IConfigurationAnnotation annotation,
      Class testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor,
      Method testMethod) {
    if (testMethod == null) {
      return;
    }

    String jvmValue = System.getProperty("methods.disable");
    if (jvmValue == null || jvmValue.trim().isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }

    List<String> methods = Arrays.asList(jvmValue.split(","));

    String fullyQualifiedMethodName =
        testMethod.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName() + "#" + testMethod.getName();
    if (methods.contains(fullyQualifiedMethodName)) {
      annotation.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
}
```

You then create a suite xml file as below:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="59840389_suite" parallel="false" configfailurepolicy="continue" verbose="2">
  <listeners>
    <listener
      class-name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn59840389.SampleAnnotationTransformer"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="59840389_test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn59840389.SampleTestClass">
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Here's the test class

```java
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestClass {
  private boolean skipMarkedBeforeTest = false;

  @BeforeTest
  public void skippingBeforeTest() {
    skipMarkedBeforeTest = true;
  }

  @BeforeTest
  public void runnableBeforeTest() {
    System.err.println("runnableBeforeTest");
  }

  @Test
  public void beforeMethod() {
    Assert.assertFalse(skipMarkedBeforeTest);
  }
}
```